# Calcular porcentaje a partir de 2 columnas mysql

Tags: mysql

Quiero crear una columna que me indique el porcentaje a partir de dos columnas las cuales son compra y afiliados, es decir compra entre afiliados * 100 %
este es el código actual

```
SELECT
IFNULL(L.LineaDescripcion,'NINGUNO') LINEA,
r.RepEstatus ESTATUS, 
r.RepresentanteID , 
CONCAT(IFNULL(r.RepNombre,' ') ,' ',IFNULL(r.RepApellido,' ')) REPRESENTANTE, 
FAZ.DESC_REGION as REGION,
(SELECT COUNT( P.TarjetaID) 
FROM  paciente P
 JOIN tarjeta T on P.TarjetaID = T.TarjetaID
WHERE(T.RepresentanteID = r.RepresentanteID and P.PacFechaAfiliacion BETWEEN '2021-01-01' and '2021-02-01')
) AFILIADAS,
(SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT V.TarjetaID)
FROM venta V 
 JOIN tarjeta T ON T.TarjetaID = V.TarjetaID 
 JOIN paciente P on P.TarjetaID = T.TarjetaID
WHERE(r.RepresentanteID = T.RepresentanteID  and P.PacFechaAfiliacion BETWEEN '2021-01-01' and '2021-02-01' )
GROUP  by r.RepresentanteID )as COMPRA
FROM representante r
LEFT JOIN representante_linea RL ON RL.RepresentanteID = r.RepresentanteID
LEFT JOIN linea L ON L.LineaID = RL.LineaID
LEFT JOIN provincia PROV ON r.ProvinciaID = PROV.ID
 JOIN (SELECT CD_PROVINCIA, DESC_REGION
FROM farmacias_zonificacion GROUP BY CD_PROVINCIA,  DESC_REGION) FAZ
ON FAZ.CD_PROVINCIA= PROV.id_provincia_sap
HAVING (AFILIADAS>0 and r.RepEstatus like 'Inactivo') or
(AFILIADAS>=0 and r.RepEstatus like 'Activo')
order by r .RepresentanteID
```

Comment: Y, ¿cuál es el problema o error? ¿Qué estás obteniendo y qué esperas obtener? [Se agredecería un fiddle con un ejemplo mínimo y verificable](https://www.db-fiddle.com/).

Comment: Quiero agregar una nueva columna con lo ya mencionado, el error es que los alias no se pueden usar para hacer el calculo, ya que me dice que las columnas son desconocidas.

Comment: *el error es que los alias no se pueden usar para hacer el calculo* pero sí puedes hacer el cálculo y asignarle un alias ¿no? Y, ¿qué hay del Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable?

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de los campos a devolver, es decir, dentro del SELECT agregarías la operación, algo como:

SELECT (compra / afiliados) * 100 AS porcentaje FROM ...

Comment: No amigo eso no funciona ya que no se puede usar los alias como las columnas normales

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).